# Combine multi row to single row and fill in the missing value by using sql, Function or ... in DB2

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I need your help i Have Raw Data Below.

```
Student Name    Period  Class
_____________________________               
Samnang         2019-03-31  0               
Samnang         2019-05-31  1               
Samnang         2019-08-31  2               
Samnang         2019-09-30  3               
Samnang         2019-10-31  4
```

And I want result below using Sql, Function or ... in DB2:

Note: Missing Month will be replaced by "M" (Mission Month)

```
Student Name    Class       
__________________________          
Samnang     0M1MM234
```

Comment: Show the code which you have tried so far

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check [this article about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question by adding details/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
  Student (Name, Period, Class) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('Samnang', DATE('2019-03-31'), 0)
, ('Samnang', DATE('2019-05-31'), 1)
, ('Samnang', DATE('2019-08-31'), 2)
, ('Samnang', DATE('2019-09-30'), 3)
, ('Samnang', DATE('2019-10-31'), 4)

, ('Samnang1', DATE('2019-01-31'), 0)
, ('Samnang1', DATE('2019-03-31'), 1)
, ('Samnang1', DATE('2019-07-31'), 2)
)
, 
DATE_RANGE AS
(
SELECT 
  Name
, MIN(PERIOD) - (DAY(MIN(PERIOD)) - 1) DAYS PERIOD_MIN
, MAX(PERIOD) - (DAY(MAX(PERIOD)) - 1) DAYS PERIOD_MAX
FROM student
GROUP BY Name
) 
, T (NAME, PERIOD, PERIOD_MAX, PERIOD_YEAR, PERIOD_MONTH) AS
(
SELECT NAME, PERIOD_MIN, PERIOD_MAX, YEAR(PERIOD_MIN), MONTH(PERIOD_MIN)
FROM DATE_RANGE
  UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, PERIOD + 1 MONTH, PERIOD_MAX, YEAR(PERIOD + 1 MONTH), MONTH(PERIOD + 1 MONTH)
FROM T
WHERE PERIOD < PERIOD_MAX
)
SELECT T.NAME, LISTAGG(COALESCE(TRIM(CHAR(S.CLASS)), 'M')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.PERIOD_YEAR, T.PERIOD_MONTH) CLASS
FROM T
LEFT JOIN STUDENT S ON S.NAME = T.NAME AND YEAR(S.PERIOD) = T.PERIOD_YEAR AND MONTH(S.PERIOD) = T.PERIOD_MONTH
GROUP BY T.NAME;

|NAME    |CLASS   |
|--------|--------|
|Samnang |0M1MM234|
|Samnang1|0M1MMM2 |
```